# how to apply recursive function on json data in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, recursion, filter

I've validation schema in js like this

```
var data = [
  {
    id: {
      label: "",
      tests: [
        {
          name: "required",
          params: "",
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    name: {
      fields: {
        firstName: {
          label: "",
          tests: [
            {
              name: "required",
              params: "",
            },
          ],
        },
        lastName: {
          label: "",
          tests: [
            {
              name: "required",
              params: "",
            },
          ],
        },
        midName: {
          label: "",
          tests: [],
        },
      },
      tests: [],
    },
  },
  {
    email: {
      label: "",
      tests: [
        {
          name: "required",
          params: "",
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    city: {
      label: "",
      tests: [],
    },
  },
  {
    details: {
      fields: {
        age: {
          label: "",
          tests: [
            {
              name: "max",
              params: {
                max: 18,
              },
            },
          ],
        },
        tests: [],
      },
    },
  },
];
```

I only want the name of the keys from array which has required field like this
var selected= ["id", "name", "email"].
For this want to create one dynamic function like if data has key:"tests" 'required' it will return the name and if data has key:"fields" it will check again for the 'tests'.

Comment: And what have you tried yourself?

Comment: It would help if `data` was a valid input.

Comment: I think I have a technique that would work.  But I'd really like to see your own work first.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
var data = [
  {
    id: {
      label: "",
      tests: [
        {
          name: "required",
          params: "",
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    name: {
      fields: {
        firstName: {
          label: "",
          tests: [
            {
              name: "required",
              params: "",
            },
          ],
        },
        lastName: {
          label: "",
          tests: [
            {
              name: "required",
              params: "",
            },
          ],
        },
        midName: {
          label: "",
          tests: [],
        },
      },
      tests: [],
    },
  },
  {
    email: {
      label: "",
      tests: [
        {
          name: "required",
          params: "",
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    city: {
      label: "",
      tests: [],
    },
  },
  {
    details: {
      fields: {
        age: {
          label: "",
          tests: [
            {
              name: "max",
              params: {
                max: 18,
              },
            },
          ],
        },
        tests: [],
      },
    },
  },
]
console.clear()
const keys = data.map(x => recursive(Object.keys(x)[0], x)).filter(x => x !== undefined)
function recursive (name, x) {
    for (let key in x) {
    if (x[key].tests !== undefined && typeof x[key].tests === "object") {
      const find = x[key].tests.find(y => y.name === "required")
      if (find) return name
    } 
    if (x[key].fields !== undefined) {
      for (let y in x[key].fields) {
        if (y !== "tests") {
                console.log(y)
          const v = recursive(parent, x[key].fields)
          if (v !== undefined) return name
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
console.log("KEYS", keys)
```

Like you said search recursive in child if we have only one time `require` in `name`field. Just you need to remember the name of your data and filter at the end, because i don't return a name so that return `undefined` if i didn't find this specific string field.

Comment: Just delete all `console.log`